# Defining variables to pass to Django models

Tags: django, django-models

The following works for me --

```
email_list = EmailList.objects.get(domain=(cd['email'].split('@')[1]))
```

But defining the 'domain' variable **before** does not --

```
domain = cd['email'].split('@')[1]
email_list = EmailList.objects.get(domain=domain)
```

When I do the latter, it raises an `"EmailList matching query does not exist"`. What accounts for this difference??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that accounts for this difference; Python variables do not change type when bound to a name.